# Consulta SQL con Count

Tags: sql, join

tengo una duda con una consulta de SQL.

Tengo las siguientes tablas

-Producto(id, nombre, id color)

-Color(id color, nombre)

Quiero lograr la consulta que me devuelva cuanto productos tengo de cada color.

Hice la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT c.id color, c. nombre, COUNT(c.id color) FROM color c
INNER JOIN producto p ON p. id Color= c. id Color
GROUP BY p. id Color
```

*LOS NOMBRES DE LAS COLUMNAS Y EN LA CONSULTA NO PONGO LOS ESPACIOS

Y logro solo una parte de lo que quiero, ya que me devuelve cuanto productos por color tengo, pero necesito que también me agregue a la respuesta los colores que tienen 0 productos. En la respuesta solo me devuelve los colores que tienen al menos 1 producto

Comment: cambia tu inner join por un left join

Answer (score 0):

Como bien comenta el compañero en los comentarios, deberías revisar el tipo de Join que realizas, ya que la INNER no es la mas adecuada para tu caso, creo que necesitarias una LEFT.

Te dejo un pictograma para que puedas conocer mejor los tipos que hay.

https://ingenieriadesoftware.es/tipos-sql-join-guia-referencia/

Answer (score 0):

Tendras que usar un having count para poder saber cuantos elementos estan repetidos dentro del group by te dejo un ejemplo.

```
SELECT p.idcolor, COUNT(p.idcolor) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM (color c
INNER JOIN productos p ON p.idcolor = c.idcolor)
GROUP BY p.idcolor
HAVING COUNT(p.idcolor) > 1;
```

Seria una cosa así. La función having count lo que realiza es decirte cuantas agrupaciones de mas de 1 item tiene el producto, los productos que tengan 0 registros no saldran.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya lo han dicho, necesitas usar un `LEFT JOIN` para que regrese todos los colores aunque no estén asignados a ningun producto. Sin embargo, es importante agrupar sobre una columna de la tabla `Producto` para que omita los nulos en el conteo y pueda mostrar ceros. De otra forma, si utilizas un valor de de la tabla `Color` puede regresar 1 aunque no haya productos.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT c.idcolor, 
       c.nombre, 
       COUNT(p.idcolor) AS NumProductos, 
       COUNT(c.idcolor) AS NumProductosIncorrecto
FROM color c
LEFT JOIN producto p ON p.idColor = c.idColor
GROUP BY c.idcolor, 
         c.nombre;
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias a todos por responder. Al final con un left join no se solucionaba el problema que tenia. La solución fue mediante una subconsulta, la cual logra que cuando un color no tiene ningún producto asociado, devuelve NULL.

Con este código lo resolví.

```sql
SELECT C.nombre, Cantidad 
FROM Colors C LEFT JOIN 
(Select Id_Color, Count(1) as Cantidad FROM Products P GROUP BY Id_Color) AS Tempo
ON C.id_Color = Tempo.Id_Color GROUP BY C.Nombre
```